# Why am I getting an unexpected "}" syntax error in php file

Tags: php, forms

I'm making a sign up form for my website, I have created my db and wrote my html and php code but I keep getting this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\example\boosie.php on line 73". If I remove it my file wont run on my browser, will just keep loading. Not sure what else is wrong, anything will help me!

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1:3307", "root", "", "boosie");

if (mysqli_connect_error()) { echo mysqli_connect_error(); exit; }

// The (?,?,?) below are parameter markers used for variable binding

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$sql = "INSERT INTO Signup (First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Password, Re_Password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $First_Name, $Last_Name, $Email, $Password, $Re_Password); // bind variables

$First_Name = $_POST['First_Name'];
$Last_Name = $_POST['Last_Name'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Password = $_POST['Password'];
$Re_Password = $_POST['Re_Password'];

$result=$stmt->execute(); // execute the prepared statement


echo "New records created successfully "; 

$stmt->close(); // close the prepared statement
$mysqli->close(); // close the database connection
}else

?>
{
    <html>
<head>
<title> Signup Form Design Tutorial </title>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="login-box">
      <div class="left-box">
        <h1> Sign Up</h1>
          <form method="post" action="boosie.php">
          <input type="text" name="First_Name" placeholder="First_Name"/>
          <input type="text" name="Last_Name" placeholder="Last_Name"/>
          <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email"/>

          <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password"/>


          <input type="password" name="Re_Password" placeholder="Retype Password"/>



          <input type="submit" name="signup-button" value="Sign Up"/>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="right-box">
          <span class="signinwith">Sign in with<br/>Social Network     </span>

        <button class="social facebook">Log in with Facebook</button>    
        <button class="social twitter">Log in with Twitter</button> 
        <button class="social google">Log in with Google+</button> 


        </div>
        <div class="or">OR</div>
    </div>

</body>    
</html>

<?php  
}
?>
```

Comment: before html starts there is issue in closing php tag

Comment: You may find the errors easier to find if you indent your code properly, this helps to understand where { and } need to match up (and make sure they are within PHP tags)

Comment: The `{` just before the `<html>` is not executed within PHP, it just in the HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your opening bracket outside of PHP tag.

Here:

```
}else

?>
{
```

Make that:

```
}else{

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my error but now when I hit submit the page refreshes and my database does not get any data. I think something is looping the html. Amateur at php :)